# MatLab: get username in Parallel Computing

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm using MatLab Parallel Computing Toolbox on several computers in my office: I've enstabilished a cluster managed by a custom scheduler (the MatLab's own kind: the MJS).

Everything seems to run smoothly as long as I run scripts and functions that have the same path on every PC (e.g. C:\Sample.m), but unfortunately I need to access to functions that are in the Dropbox folder of every computer (for example the file C:\Users\myusername\Dropbox\Sample.m).

To solve the problem, I tried something like this:

```
parfor j=1:100
   myusername=getenv('username');
   cd(['C:\Users\',myusername,'\Dropbox'])
   Sample(1,2,3);
end
```

But with this code the `cd` function set the current folder in C:\Users\SYSTEM\Dropbox and obviously it can't find Sample.m in it.

Has anybody any way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a function called "nome":

```
function [username]=nome()
     username='Stefano';
end
```

I put this function in the `matlabroot` in every PC on the cluster BUT instead of putting `'Stefano'` in each one I put the name of the user in which the Dropbox function is placed. The I had to use `cd` in the right way:

```
cdorig=cd;
spmd
    cd(matlabroot);
    username=nome();
end

spmd
   mypath=strsplit(cdorig,'\');
    mypath{3}=username;
    cd(fullfile(mypath{1:end}));  
end
```

And it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here. First, you could simply compute your username outside the `parfor` loop

```
myusername = getenv('username');
parfor ...
    ...
    cd(['c:\Users\', myusername, '\Dropbox']);
    ...
end
```

If you're running a more recent version of MATLAB, then there is automatic dependency analysis that should transfer the functions that you need to the workers when required - which version are you using? You can use [`listAutoAttachedFiles`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/listautoattachedfiles.html) to see what files have been attached to your pool.

Finally, if you get your MJS administrator to [run at security level 3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/mdce/set-mjs-cluster-security.html), then the workers will run with your credentials, and `getenv('username')` will behave as you expect on the workers.

Comment: The real problem is I'm running my cluster on many computer with many users, so if I use the first alternative you proposed It'll use a path like C:\Users\Stefano\Dropbox for every computer in the pool, which is not correct. 
For the second alternative, I'm using R2012a and I can't find  listAutoAttachedFiles ...do you know if it's available.

Comment: Ah. Automatic attachment of files was added in R2013a. http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/release-notes.html . So, it sounds like you need the final option to use security level 3.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad formatted response but I couldn't edit it. I tried the third solution but unluckily I need to use on the remote computer that I'm using its own credentials, not mine, so it doesn't work.